# Rendering google map using gmaps4rails through Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I want to render the map only on demand(to minimize the loading time), means some link like 'Show Map' should render the map in a specified div. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the 'to_gmaps4rails' method described here:
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Methods

Basically, do:

```
<%=raw assets_hash.to_gmaps4rails(true) %>
```

This will render only the js necessary to display your assets.

So include gmaps4rails.js and .css (if necessary), and the div to host the map.